# Non-trivial subsets $A$ satisfying $m^{*}(A) = m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*}(A \cap E^c)$ for all $ E \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I was studying measure theory from Royden's book and here is the definition of a "Lebesgue measurable set" $E$:

> **Definition.** *A set E is said to be **measurable** provided for any set A,*
> $$ m^{*}(A) = m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*}(A \cap E^c). \qquad (1)$$

Here the sets are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $m^{*}$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

I was wondering if there are sets with the roles of $E$ and $A$ reversed, i.e., are there sets $A$ such that for every set $E$, $A$ satisfies $(1)$?
I can easily see that the sets $\phi$, $\mathbb{R}$ and countable sets satisfy this condition but I am unable to think of non-trivial examples.

Comment: If $A$ is a Lebesgue nullset then this is true, with $0 = 0+0$.  If $m^*(A) = \infty$ then it is true, $\infty = \infty + \infty$ by subadditivity.  But I suspect there are no examples with $0 < m^*(A) < \infty$.

Comment: So how can I go about proving that? Any possible approaches I can try?

Comment: My guess would be: if $0 < m^*(A) < + \infty$ and $E$ is a Bernstein set, then $(1)$ has strict inequality.